# Scanl expressed as fold

Tags: beginner, haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Inspired by the [learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application) exercise to express map with fold I wrote an implementation of scanl by means of a fold.

```haskell
scanl2 :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl2 f z xs = reverse $ foldl (\a x -> (f (head a) x): a) [z] xs
```

I have the idea that in terms of performance it kinda is up to par with standard scanl but I am wondering whether I could improve anything both in terms of performance, idiomacy, style, etc. I am a Haskell novice with modest functional programming (Scala, some Clojure) background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the laziness of `scanl`, you'll need to write this using `foldr`.  Doing that requires a trick - the same trick as is involved in writing `foldl` as `foldr`.  I wrote in some detail of my derivation of how that trick works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456313/how-to-implement-delete-with-foldr-in-haskell/27458645#27458645).

For what it's worth, using that trick to write `scanl` using `foldr` looks like this:

```
scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl f z xs = foldr go (const []) xs z
  where
    go x continue acc = let next = f acc x in next : continue next
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `reverse` is generally a bad idea for performance — especially since Haskell lists can be infinite!  Observe:

```haskell
*Main> let triangularNumbers = scanl (+) 0 [1, 2 ..]
*Main> let triangularNumbers2 = scanl2 (+) 0 [1, 2 ..]
*Main> take 5 triangularNumbers
[0,1,3,6,10]
*Main> take 5 triangularNumbers2          -- hangs forever
```

Comment: Come to think of it,  this breaks laziness to.  Because a take5 scanl2 someOpp 0 [1..1000000] would require 1M things to be computed,  would it not?

Comment: Right. That is a different way of characterizing the same problem.